# add % value programmatically

Tags: apache-flex

I have the following code which gives me an error. I want to add the width property programmatically and in %:

> firstcombo.width = 90%;

But that gives me the following error:

- 1084 syntax error expecting
  rightparen before colon

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
firstcombo.percentWidth = 90;
```

Comment: See the Adobe LiveDocs: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentWidth -- I think this is the OP's intent.

Comment: +1 I have to agree with you Matt, that looks like the intent, and the correct way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

The width combobox property is a Number. you need to set it accordingly.
Something like firstCombo.width = .9 * X where X is the value you want 90% of.